# If use git to delete the remote branch, an error will be displayed

Tags: git

- macOS 10.15.5
- zsh 5.7.1
- git version 2.27.0

```
git push --delete origin xxxx

remote: fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/heads/xxxx': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
remote: Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
remote: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
To user:~/xxxx.git
 - [deleted]         xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually means you have a file `xxxx` or a tag `xxxx` on the remote side, which has the same name as the *branch* `xxxx` you are trying to delete (again, on the remote repository)

`git push --delete -- origin xxx` would clearly separate options from arguments.
But you still need to check for similarly named file/tags on the remote side.

Comment: @Coco Yes, which is why you need to check the remote repository content (for similar tags or files)

Comment: There are no files or tags similar to remote repositories.

Comment: @Coco OK: do you have a tag or a file names like your branch in your *local* repository? (local: the one you are pushing from)